# Printing in C++ Visual Studio

Tags: c++

Really simple question that I can't seem to find the answer for.
In C++, How do I print a `%` sign?

For example,

```
int a = 100;
int b = 25;
int c;
c = (100/25)
printf("Your Answer is %d% ");
```

Output: `"Your Answer is 4%"`

Thanks.

Comment: That is more than likely not the output to the program you posted.  What you posted leads to undefined behavior due to the missing argument to `printf` (format string specifies at least one integer, and you didn't provide it).  This is why you should use `cout`, so that mistakes like this don't happen.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `"%%"` in a format specifier to print the character `'%'`.

```
printf("Your Answer is %d%%\n", c);
```

You can also use `%c` in the format specifier and use `'%'` as the argument.

```
printf("Your Answer is %d%c\n", c, '%');
```

Answer (score 1):

For C++ you can, and should, use `std::cout` instead of `printf`, which is from C.

```
#include <iostream>
// ...
int quotient = 100 / 25;
std::cout << "Your answer is " << quotient << "% " << std::endl;
```

Yours is an easily avoidable mistake if you use language-specific libraries, such as `iostream` in this case.